# AppEngine Billing: Difference between Total, Active and Billed Instances

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine

I'm trying to understand why my app engine application is billing me so high...

I have just one F1 instance up, and app engine is billing me 4 instances, why? Someone can explain me how google do this count?

Instances Graph:

[image]

Active Instances:

[image]

Configuration:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bruno, did you manage to find the answer to this post? Is there a more detailed explanation somewhere in the docs?